# Word related to physical attraction of smoking?

Tags: single-word-requests

A long while ago I happened upon a trivia website that mentioned there's a word related to the act of smoking being attractive -- either that smoking is becoming of a certain person, or that a certain person finds smoking inherently attractive, I can't remember which.

I've lost the word and have been unable to find it in my searches. I'm beginning to doubt the original veracity of the claim that such a word is in official usage!

Anyone know the word I have in mind?

I'll include two possible sample sentences since it could be one of two distinct meanings:

#### Possible Meaning 1

> He's not much of a looker, but he sure is **_____**. When he packs his Camels and puffs away, I'm transfixed.

#### Possible Meaning 2

> Though he never partook himself, he was a _____ and always wound up with tobacco fiends for partners.

Or some minor variations (part-of-speech changes, e.g.) thereof.

Comment: Wiktionary suggests that *tobaccophile* is, or has become, a "real word".  It would fit in your second sentence, but not your first, so it's clearly not the one you are looking for.  (Also, I have that tip-of-my-tongue feeling that I know which word you want, but it refuses to emerge.)

Comment: @torek I've clarified the question a bit. I'm not after a multipurpose word -- it's just that my recollection is vague enough that I only am sure it was related to smoking and physical attraction. The word wasn't tobaccophile, but that could certainly work as a proxy.

Comment: This is not the word I am also now seeking, but ... see [capnolagnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoking_fetishism).

Comment: Well, [*smoking*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVOa3xhl0bg) is itself slang for *attractive*.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are grasping for is

*allure* or *alluring*.

For example,

> He's not much of a looker, but he sure is alluring. When he packs his Camels and puffs away, I'm transfixed.